# Cypress: Dynamic Tests: Validate rows in table

Tags: cypress

The goal is to iterate over a table and create a test dynamically for each row to validate its status. Table example:
[image: Table, 1rst column GUID labels, 3rd column status]

Aware of [Cypress Examples: Dynamic tests](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/tree/master/examples/fundamentals__dynamic-tests), however, provided examples addresses iterating over a static list of base types (`string`, `number`) and not gathered children of `JQuery<HTMLElement>`.

Rows are grouped by the first column labeled with GUID labels. The code below collects rows label contains a specific GUID. The added pseudo injection of test `it()` does not work nor do I expect it would, but this is what I am trying to accomplish testing each row's status with specific GUID:

```
it('TEST Iterate rows matching GUID', () => {
  cy.fixture('esign').then($esignStore => {
   
   expect($esignStore).to.have.property('requestUUID').to.be.a('string').not.empty;
    cy.get('table[data-qa="act_ops_log_table"]').within(() => {
      cy.log('Ops Logs table found');
      cy.get('tbody[data-qa="act_ops_log_table_body"]').then(() => {
        cy.get('tr');
        cy.get('td');
        cy.get('td:nth-child(1)').each(($tableCell, $index, $list) => {
          const textEnvelope = $tableCell.text();
          if (textEnvelope.includes($esignStore.requestUUID)) {

            // pseudo-example of dynamically added test: start
            // it(`TEST ${$index}`, () => {
              cy.get('td:nth-child(3)')
                .eq($index)
                .then($field => {
                  const textStatus = $field.text();
                  expect(textStatus, 'succeeded');
                });
            // });
            // pseudo-example of dynamically added test: end

          }
        });
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Approaches appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 5):

You cannot create tests dynamically.

Cypress parses the spec file to find out what tests are present before the Cypress commands even start to run.

The best you can do is add extra logging to mark each tested row.

```js
cy.get('tbody tr', {log:false}).each(($tr, index) => {

  // Log beginning of row test
  cy.then(() => Cypress.log({
    displayName: 'Row test',
    message: `TEST ${index}`,
  }))

  cy.wrap($tr, {log:false}).find('td:nth-child(1)', {log:false}).then($firstCol => {
    const textEnvelope = $firstCol.text();
    if (textEnvelope.includes(esignStore.requestUUID)) {
      cy.wrap($firstCol, {log:false}).siblings({log:false}).eq(1, {log:false})
        .should('have.text', 'succeed')
    } else {
      cy.log(`Row ${index} - not required requestUUID`)
    }
  })
})
```

[image]

---

Or pre-filtering the required rows so that only those matching `requestUUID` are tested

```js
cy.get('tbody tr', {log:false}).each(($tr, index) => {
  .filter(`:has(td:nth-child(1):contains(${esignStore.requestUUID}))`, {log:false})
  .each(($tr, index) => {

    // Log beginning of row test
    cy.then(() => Cypress.log({
      displayName: 'Row test',
      message: `TEST ${index}`,
    }))

    cy.wrap($tr, {log:false})
      .find('td:nth-child(3)', {log:false})
      .should('have.text', 'succeed')
  })
```

[image]

Comment: Appreciate your response.

Comment: My changes for this problem are too long to be within a comment. Created a new question. Thank you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69095677/cypress-adding-tests-dynamically-within-a-wrap

Comment: No problem, but the other way doesn't work either - no Cypress commands run until the number of tests have been established.