# Cypress: Adding tests dynamically within a wrap

Tags: cypress

Trying a way to dynamically add Cypress test dynamically, iterating over rows over a table. Example table:

[image]

Note, this is an extension of a previous question, but the change is too long as a comment and has some progress: [Cypress: Dynamic Tests: Validate rows in table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69091050/cypress-dynamic-tests-validate-rows-in-table/69095114#69095114)

I broke up the code into two tests: one to collect filtered rows, and the next test to iterate iterated over rows to determine if the status cell has 'succeeded'. This is good but each row is not a separate test.

```
    let rowsUUID;

    it('TEST LOGS table rows UUID', () => {
      cy.fixture('esign').then($esignStore => {
        cy.wait(2000);
        cy.get('table[data-qa="act_ops_log_table"]').within(() => {
          cy.get('tbody[data-qa="act_ops_log_table_body"]').then(() => {
            cy.get('tbody[data-qa="act_ops_log_table_body"]')
              .children('tr')
              .then($rows => {
                rowsUUID = $rows.filter(index => $rows.eq(index).is(`:contains(${$esignStore.requestUUID})`));
                cy.log('rowsUUID count', rowsUUID.length);
                expect(rowsUUID).not.undefined;
                expect(rowsUUID).length.gt(0);
              });
          });
        });
      });
    });

    it('TEST LOGS table rows UUID iterate', () => {
      // Problem 'rowsUUID' is NOT undefined here
      Cypress._.range(0, rowsUUID.length).forEach(($rowIndex: number) => {
        const rowUUID = rowsUUID[$rowIndex];
        Cypress._.range(0, rowUUID.cells.length).forEach(($cellIndex: number) => {
          cy.log(`${$cellIndex}`);
          expect(rowUUID.cells[2].textContent.replace(/\s/g, '')).to.be.a('string').equals('succeeded');
        });
      });
    });
```

To dynamically add a test per row, I followed the approach provided in [Cypress Examples](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/blob/master/examples/fundamentals__dynamic-tests/cypress/integration/request-spec.js).

So, I replaced the second aforementioned test with the Cypress._.range wrapping around a test per row. However, the global `rowsUUID` is undefined.

```
    let rowsUUID;

    it('TEST LOGS table rows UUID', () => {
      cy.fixture('esign').then($esignStore => {
        cy.wait(2000);
        cy.get('table[data-qa="act_ops_log_table"]').within(() => {
          cy.get('tbody[data-qa="act_ops_log_table_body"]').then(() => {
            cy.get('tbody[data-qa="act_ops_log_table_body"]')
              .children('tr')
              .then($rows => {
                rowsUUID = $rows.filter(index => $rows.eq(index).is(`:contains(${$esignStore.requestUUID})`));
                cy.log('rowsUUID count', rowsUUID.length);
                expect(rowsUUID).not.undefined;
                expect(rowsUUID).length.gt(0);
              });
          });
        });
      });
    });

    // Problem 'rowsUUID' is undefined here
    Cypress._.range(0, rowsUUID.length).forEach(($rowIndex: number) => {
      it(`row # ${$rowIndex}`, () => {
        const rowUUID = rowsUUID[$rowIndex];
        Cypress._.range(0, rowUUID.cells.length).forEach(($cellIndex: number) => {
          cy.log(`${$cellIndex}`);
          expect(rowUUID.cells[2].textContent.replace(/\s/g, '')).to.be.a('string').equals('succeeded');
        });
      });
    });
```

How can I get the global `rowsUUID` to be defined in order to add tests dynamically per row?

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't work either - no Cypress commands run until the number of tests have been established.

I tried to do this for days. The only way to do it is to run run the first test (the one that counts the rows) in another test run, then save the results to a fixture, and read that fixture in the second run.

You can coordinate the two runs using the Module API, but it's a lot of work.

For anyone following - [Dynamic Tests: Validate rows in table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69095114/16826419)

Comment: Thank you, appreciate your contribution. I am very curious about your comment "You can coordinate the two runs using the Module API, but it's a lot of work." Checking this out as well