# Pre-scan web page for dynamic tests

Tags: cypress

Looking for a definitive answer to the question posed by @JeffTanner [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69095677/cypress-adding-tests-dynamically-within-a-wrap) about **generating dynamic tests**. From that question and the Cypress samples, it's clear that we need to know  the number of tests required before generating them.

**Problem**

We have a web page containing a table of Healthcare analytic data that is refreshed many times during the day. Each refresh the team must check the data, and to divvy up the work we run each row as a separate test. But the number of rows varies every time which means I must count the rows and update the system on each run. Looking for a way to programmatically get the row count.

The HTML is a table of `<tbody><tr></tr></tbody>`, so the following is enough to get the count but I can't run it in a `beforeEach()`, the error thrown is "No tests found"

```js
let rowCount;

beforeEach(() => {
  cy.visit('/analytics')
  cy.get('tbody tr').then($els => rowCount = $els.length)
})

Cypress._.times(rowCount => {
  it('process row', () => {
    ...
  })
})
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `before:run` event fires before the tests start, you can scan the web page there.

Set the event listener in `setupNodeEvents()`. Cypress commands won't run here, but you can use  equivalent Node commands.

```js
const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      on('before:run', async (details) => {
        try {
          const fetch = require('node-fetch');
          const fs = require('fs-extra');
          const jsdom = require("jsdom");
          const { JSDOM } = jsdom;                           
          
          const response = await fetch(config.env.prescan);  // default below 
          const body = await response.text();                // or pass in command line

          const dom = new JSDOM(body);
          const rows = dom.window.document.body.querySelectorAll('tr')  // query

          // save results
          fs.writeJson('./cypress/fixtures/analytics-rows.json', {rows:rows.length})

        } catch (error) {
          console.log('error:', error)
        }
      })
    },
  },
  env: {
    prefetch: 'url-for-analytics-page'
  }
})
```

**Test**

```js
import {rows} from './cypress/fixtures/analytics-rows.json'  // read row count

Cypress._.times(rows, (row) => {
  it(`tests row ${row}`, () => {
    ...
  })
}
```

Answer (score 6):

One possibility is to run the above Cypress test in a `pretest` script which will always run before your main test script.

```js
// package.json

{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "pretest": "npx cypress run --spec cypress/e2e/pre-scan.cy.js",
    "test": "npx cypress run --spec cypress/e2e/main-test.cy.js",
  }
}
```

```js
// pre-scan.cy.js

it('scans for table row count', () => {
  cy.visit('/analytics');
  cy.get('tbody tr').then($els => {
    const rowCount = $els.length;
    cy.writeFile('cypress/fixtures/rowcount.json', rowCount);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add a script `scan-for-rows.js` to the project `scripts` folder, like this

```js
const rp = require('request-promise');
const $ = require('cheerio');
const fs = require('fs-extra');

rp('my-url')
  .then(function(html) {
    const rowCount = $('big > a', html).length
    fs.writeJson('row-count.json', {rowCount})
  })
  .catch(function(err){
    //handle error
  });
```

Then in `package.json` call a pre-test script every time a new version of the web page appears.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a way to get the row count in the spec file without using extra packages, plugins, test hooks, or npm scripts.

Basically, you can create a separate module that makes a synchronous HTTP request using the `XMLHTTPRequest` class to the `/analytics` endpoint and use the browser's `DOMParser` class to find the return the number of `<tr>` tags.

```js
// scripts/get-row-count.js
export function getRowCount() {
  let request = new XMLHttpRequest();

  // Set async to false because Cypress will not wait for async functions to finish before looking for it() statements
  request.open('GET', '/analytics', false); 

  request.send(null);

  const document = new DOMParser().parseFromString(request.response, 'text/html');

  const trTags = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('tr'));

  return trTags.length;
};
```

Then in the spec file, import the new function and now you can get an updated row count whenever you need it.

```js
import { getRowCount } from '../scripts/get-row-count';

Cypress._.times(getRowCount() => {
  it('process row', () => {
    ...
  })
})
```

The reason for `XMLHTTPRequest` instead of fetch is because it allows synchronous requests to be made. Synchronous requests are needed because Cypress won't wait for async requests to come back before parsing for `it()` blocks.

With this, you always have the most up to date row count without it going stale.

Comment: [Synchronous request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests#synchronous_request) - Synchronous XHR is now in deprecation state.