# Cypress iterate over the array and update value dynamically after new value has been fetched

Tags: cypress

How data value can be updated after the new value is fetched cy.interception?

```js
let data = [
  {
    track: 'Track 1',
    case: [{name: 'case 1.1'}, {name: 'case 1.2'}],
  },
];

describe(`All test`, {tags: '@testConcept'}, () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    // LOGIN and fetching new data and updating 
    data = [
      {
        track: 'Track 3',
        case: [{name: 'case 3.1'}, {name: 'case 3.2'}],
      },
    ];
  });

  data.forEach((el) => {
    describe(`Test :`, () => {
      it(`Test Track :  ${JSON.stringify(el.track)}`, () => {
        cy.log(el.track); // expected Track 3
      });

      el.case.forEach((el2) => {
        it(`Test case :  ${JSON.stringify(el2.name)}`, () => {
          cy.log(el2.name); // expected Track 3.1
        });
      });
    });
  });
});
```

The data variable is getting hosted and the value is not getting changed

Attaching image on how the test look like [image]

Answer (score 2):

From this answer [Pre-scan web page for dynamic tests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72795255/16997707), it is clear you would need to do the fetch data in the `before:run` hook.

There is no possibility to change the number of `it()` calls in the test while the test is running, even in a `beforeEach()` hook.

**cypress.config.js**

```js
const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      on('before:run', async (details) => {
        try {
          const response = await fetch(data-url-here);  
          const data = await response.json();   
          config.env.data = data;           

        } catch (error) {
          console.log('error:', error)
        }
      })
      return config;
    },
  },
})
```

**generalized pattern for data-driven tests**

```js
let data = [
  {
    track: 'Track 1',
    case: [{name: 'case 1.1'}, {name: 'case 1.2'}],
  },
];
const newData = Cypress.env('data')
data = [...data, ...newData]

describe(`All test`, {tags: '@testConcept'}, () => {

  data.forEach((el) => {
    describe(`Test :`, () => {
      it(`Test Track :  ${JSON.stringify(el.track)}`, () => {
        cy.log(el.track); // expected Track 3
      });

      el.case.forEach((el2) => {
        it(`Test case :  ${JSON.stringify(el2.name)}`, () => {
          cy.log(el2.name); // expected Track 3.1
        });
      });
    });
  });
})
```