# Cypress Dynamic Data with dynamic Test titles

Tags: cypress

I am new to Cypress and trying to accomplish something like below

1. Query an endpoint to get the array of data
2. For every data in the array, dynamically create the test case title.

Tried the following

```
   describe('Some RANDOM TESTSS', () => {
    let endTimes;
    before(() => {
      cy.task('getEndTimes').then((da) => {
        endTimes = da;
      });
    });
    describe(' I am going to test here ', () => {
      it('should have access to myObject', () => {
        expect(endTimes).to.exist;
      });
      it('Do something ', () => {
        endTimes.forEach((endTime, index) => {
          it(`should vvalidate for ${endTime.recordName} `, () => {
            expect(endTime.expectedEndTime).to.be.equals(endTime.actualEndTime);
          });
        })
      })

    })
```

The challenge i am facing is I could not get the last it "should vvalidate for ${endTime.recordName}" printed.
any suggestions ?
I could not get the

Comment: I think this answer [Pre-scan web page for dynamic tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72766346/pre-scan-web-page-for-dynamic-tests) does a similar thing - using the `before:run` hook to fetch the information that will set up the dynamic tests.

Comment: You seem to be using something similar inside a task, but the problem with that is the task will only run after Cypress has set up the tests.

Comment: Also get rid of nested `it()`, it's not valid syntax.

Comment: @TesterDick The answer posted in " Pre-scan web page for dynamic tests " helped. Thanks for pointing that out